# Nesting multiple direct descendant selectors in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Not sure if it's possible or not but this has been bugging me for a while.

Is it possible in SASS to select multiple direct descendants within a nested block?

```
// This works
div
{
  > .one
  {
    /* ... */
  }
}

// This doesn't work
div
{
  > .one,
  > .two
  {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works, you do something wrong. More then, you can look at compiled css here: http://sass-lang.com/try.html , in your case it provides:

```
div > .one {
  /* ... */ }

div > .one,
div > .two {
  /* ... */ }
```

So it works.

Comment: Ah you're right. I use the Mindscape Web Workbench VS2010 addon, looks like it does actually save without errors it's just a (very annoying) syntax error underline that had me thinking it doesn't work. Thanks, I'm going to go let Mindscape know.